# Inserting data to table psycopg2 with no duplicates

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am new to psycopg2. I have to insert data into the table with no duplicates. So, first I created a temporary table where I dumped all the data. And then, I check and add the data to the actual table.
Here is the code till now:

```
for eachline in content:
       pmid ,first_name, last_name,initial,article_title,journal,language = eachline.split("\t")
       cur.execute ("INSERT INTO AUTHOR_PMID(pmid, Author_lastname, Author_firstname, Author_initial,Article_title)
                           SELECT DISTINCT (pmid, Author_lastname, Author_firstname, Author_initial,Article_title) 
                                 FROM AUTHOR_PMID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT "X" FROM AUTHOR_pmid_temp 
                                     WHERE 
                                        AUTHOR_pmid_temp.pmid = AUTHOR_PMID.pmid
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_lastname = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_lastname 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_firstname = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_firstname 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_initial = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_initial 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Article_title = AUTHOR_PMID.Article_title);")
   con.commit()


error: syntax error.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: string multilines mean you need """xxx""" but the code you post here is "xxx"

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT "X" ... ` -->> `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting query with triple quotes instead of single like below

```
for eachline in content:
       pmid ,first_name, last_name,initial,article_title,journal,language = eachline.split("\t")
       cur.execute ("""INSERT INTO AUTHOR_PMID(pmid, Author_lastname, Author_firstname, Author_initial,Article_title)
                           SELECT DISTINCT (pmid, Author_lastname, Author_firstname, Author_initial,Article_title) 
                                 FROM AUTHOR_PMID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT "X" FROM AUTHOR_pmid_temp 
                                     WHERE 
                                        AUTHOR_pmid_temp.pmid = AUTHOR_PMID.pmid
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_lastname = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_lastname 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_firstname = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_firstname 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Author_initial = AUTHOR_PMID.Author_initial 
                                        AND AUTHOR_pmid_temp.Article_title = AUTHOR_PMID.Article_title);""")
   con.commit()
```

For more info, please [check here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) !!!